# Jboss 7 ,how to migrate into infinispan 6

Tags: java, caching, jboss, infinispan

`Jboss 7` is by default using `infinispan 5.2`. How can I Migrate it into latest `infinispan 6` release?

Comment: easy answer - switch to jboss 8 (wildfly)

Comment: @radai is it a stable version?

Comment: CR1. not stable but very close.

Comment: I want to use infinispan in production. so cant able to take risk. Thinking to use infinispan 5.2, so jboss 7 will support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the following steps,

1. Got to the `Infifnispan` download page http://infinispan.org/download/
2. Download the `As7 module`s. Inside of that you will get the modules which is required to be  updated
3. Copy the folders `6.0,commons,persistence` and `tree` inside `DOWNLOADED_FOLDER\org\infinispan` into `JBOSS_7_HOME\modules\org\infinispan` folder
4. Add the folder  `6.0` inside `DOWNLOADED_FOLDER\org\infinispan\cachestore\jdbc` into  `JBOSS_7_HOME\modules\org\infinispan\cachestore\jdbc` folder
5. Add  the folder `6.0` inside `DOWNLOADED_FOLDER\org\infinispan\cachestore\remote` into `JBOSS_7_HOME\modules\org\infinispan\cachestore\remote` folder
6. Do the same for `jqroups` also
7. Now while adding dependency of your application to Infinispan (either using `<global-modules>` in `standalone.xml` or by using `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`) add `slot="6.0"` like,

   ```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
       <global-modules>
           <module name="org.infinispan" slot="6.0"/>
           <module name="org.infinispan.client.hotrod" slot="6.0"/>
       </global-modules>
   </subsystem>
   ```

Done! Now Jboss will use the latest version version of `Infinispan`

**Note: You can also use `WildFly` version of `Jboss`, it is shipped with `Infinispan 6`**